# The method in Vue runs twice on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Why does the method set runs twice? You can see the console when you click the star.
If I remove `@click="set(rating)"` nothing happens so not like it is again called elsewhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/q22tqoLu/

**HTML**

```
<div id="star-app" v-cloak>
            <star-rating value="0"></star-rating>
        </div>

        <template id="template-star-rating">
            <div class="star-rating">
                <label
                class="star-rating__star"
                v-for="rating in ratings"
                :class="{'is-selected': ((value >= rating) && value != null), 'is-disabled': disabled}"
                @mouseover="star_over(rating)"
                @mouseout="star_out"
                @click="set(rating)">
                <input
                class="star-rating star-rating__checkbox"
                type="radio"
                :name="name"
                :disabled="disabled"
                :id="id"
                :required="required"
                v-model="value">
                ★
            </label>
        </div>
    </template>
```

**JS**

```
  'use strict';

    Vue.component('star-rating', {
        template: '#template-star-rating',
        data: function data() {
            return {
                value: null,
                temp_value: null,
                ratings: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            };
        },
        props: {
            'name': String,
            'value': null,
            'id': String,
            'disabled': Boolean,
            'required': Boolean
        },
        methods: {
            star_over: function star_over(index) {
                if (this.disabled) {
                    return;
                }

                this.temp_value = this.value;
                this.value = index;
            },
            star_out: function star_out() {
                if (this.disabled) {
                    return;
                }

                this.value = this.temp_value;
            },
            set: function set(value) {
                if (this.disabled) {
                    return;
                }

          // This runs twice
          console.log(value);

                this.temp_value = value;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#star-app'
    });
```

The code is based on older version from someone, here it also doubles https://codepen.io/sktwentysix/pen/oZwXjN

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you move `@click="set(rating)"` to `<input/>` instead of `<label/>`, it will run once.

Comment: I really want to understand why/how this works. Can you give like an insight on why the function executes twice if it's not placed on the input tag? For me, my label was a parent element and it had another inner element which was the parent container for the input element. So it's only your solution that worked for me and the other solutions stating to using click.prevent or click.stop on the parent element didn't.

Comment: Here is WHY.  Clicking on a label will also pass the focus to and generate a click on the associated input.  This is for accessibility.  So 1 click event for clicking the label, and 1 click event for clicking the input.

Answer (score 20):

```
@click.stop="clickfunction($event)"
```

This will stop next calls and will call function only once.

Comment: This one is more useful. Because sometimes when you are giving `@click` on some components, then you cannot move the `@click` to inner elements.

Answer (score 19):

It is a default browser behavior. Clicking on the `<label>` will trigger 2 clicks, one for `<label>` and one for `<input>`.

Way to avoid that is to add `@click.prevent` to your `<label>` tag.

Answer (score 8):

If it doesn't affect your program, change the event from `click` to `mouseup`.

```
@mouseup="set(rating)"
```

Comment: Hi Oussema, thank you so much, do you know why @click will let the method be called twice? I tried mouseup, then the funciton will be called only once, it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I used `prevent` for @click and @submit for avoiding bubbling.

```
@click.prevent="action"
@submit.prevent="action"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@click.once='set(rating)'`
this will execute the function only once.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use new version of vue. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js
You are using really old 0.12.16 and your problem seems like a bug of this old version.
You can set this in settings / JavaScript.

Comment: The behavior the OP describes happens in modern (2.*) versions of Vue as well.

Comment: Yup experiencing something similar on 2.5.16.

Comment: In my case, i upgrade boostrap-vue to 2.11.0 .
And I have no idea what problem i have solved.....